# In scala is it possible for a trait to extend a class which needs parameters?

Tags: scala, inheritance, extends, traits

I know a trait can extend a class which has an empty parameter constructor:

```
class Foo
trait Bar extends Foo
```

but is it possible to extend a class which constructor has some parameters?

```
class Foo(b: Boolean)
trait Bar extends Foo(true)
```

Is it possible to achieve this? It seems it's not possible. but why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you just can't give constructor arguments:

```
trait Bar extends Foo { ... }
```

But to instantiate it you need to call the constructor as well:

```
new Foo(false) with Bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the arg a `val` seems to work.

```
scala> class Foo(val b: Boolean)
defined class Foo

scala> trait Bar extends Foo {override val b = true}
defined trait Bar
```

This also works if you make the class a `case class` which automatically turns the args in to vals.

**EDIT**

As @Aleksey has pointed out, this compiles but it's a trait that can't be instantiated so, no, it still doesn't seem possible.  You'll have to make Bar a class.

```
scala> class Bar extends Foo(false) {println(b)}
defined class Bar

scala> new Bar
false
```

Comment: can you instantiate it?